# Definition of a dominating function and the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Tags: measure-theory

I apologise if this is a rather simplistic or even silly question, but I am confused with the word "dominated" in Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT) since I can find no definition of a dominating function in the textbook I am following, rather I can only find a definition in relation to measures.

In the DCT it is assumed we have a sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ of real measurable functions where $|f_{n}|\leq g$ almost everywhere for all $n$, and where $g$ is integrable. Now I can clearly see from various discussions on the DCT that $g$ is considered to be the dominating function, but I cannot find any definition to confirm this. The only definition I can find is related to measures and absolute continuity:

The measure $v$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the measure $\mu$ if for all $A\in\mathscr{F}$, $\mu(A)=0$ implies $v(A)=0$. In the text I am following this is written as $v<<\mu$ which means $v$ is dominated by $\mu$.

Am I right in assuming there is nothing linking these two uses of the word dominating?

Comment: Yes. If $g$ is integrable and $|f_n|\le g$ a.e., then $g$ is referred to as a "dominating function" for the sequence $(f_n)$.

Comment: Many thanks David.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given two positive functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f$ dominates $g$, let
$$\nu(A) = \int_A g d\mu, \qquad \eta(A) = \int_A f d\mu.$$
We note that $\nu(A) \leq \eta(A)$ for all measurable sets $A$.  In particular, $\nu(A)=0$ for all $\eta$-null sets $A$, so that $\nu \ll \eta$.  In this sense,

*Domination of functions implies absolute continuity of the induced measures.*

Of course, the converse is wildly false.  For example, the measures induced by $f=2$ and $g=1$ are absolutely continuous with respect to each other, whereas $f$ dominates $g$ (and *not* conversely).

I suppose you could use the Radon-Nikodym theorem to further analyze this situation.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. Presumably when you say g dominates f you mean $|f|\leq g$ where g is integrable? Given the link you have shown with measures, this now makes sense to call $g$ a dominating function. However given that $|f|\leq g$ should we not have $\eta(A) \leq \nu(A)$ and so $\nu<<\eta$?

Comment: @dandar  Thanks for that; I'll make the fix.